# Custom View: Redraw view canvas on Press

Tags: android, canvas, motionevent

I'm working on custom view, which have to draw custom canvas when pressed and other if not. I have basically overriden only methods `onMeasure` and `onDraw`. In Constructor I have set: `setFocusable(true)` and `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)`

```
public class CircularImageView extends ImageView{
    //...
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // ...
        if (isPressed() || isSelected() || isFocused()){
            // code when pressed
        }
        else{
            // otherwise
        }
    }
}
```

I want this effect: view looks like pressed after `onDown` and like non-pressed after `onUp`/`onCancel` motion event. Normally I was using `<selector>` but now i have to do a little bit of work with canvas. (one draws circle around view, other some background effects)

How can I set canvas for different press states?

Comment: you should extend a Drawable class and do your drawing depending on Drawable.getState(), note it has to be stateful: isStateful has to return true

Comment: thanks based on "stateful" and "extend Drawable" i have found this article [link](http://shiki.me/blog/android-button-background-image-pressedhighlighted-and-disabled-states-without-using-multiple-images/). Will write answer if succeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) I was able to create complete solutions so here is it.

If you want to create custom view in which have to be your custom drawings for different touch states (pressed, selected, focused etc.) and you didn't know whether this view will be placed inside other View that can intercept touch events or the view structure is even more difficult. You should implement the behavior as follows

1. Create custom [`Drawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html)
2. in overriden method [`isStateful()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#isStateful%28%29) return true value (needed to hold different states)
3. override [`onStateChange`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#onStateChange%28int%5B%5D%29) method and call [`invalidateSelf()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#invalidateSelf%28%29) if state was changed.
4. override [`draw`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) method to implement custom drawing based on drawableState (see [`getState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getState%28%29) method)
5. in custom view override method that should draw drawable (for example `setImageDrawable`, `setBackground`... depends on your needs)
6. in the method call supermethod with your custom Drawable class

Example:

```
public class CircularImageView extends ImageView{

    @Override
    public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        super.setImageDrawable(new CustomDrawable(
            ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap()));
    }

    protected class CustomDrawable extends Drawable {
        // 
        private Bitmap bitmap;

        public CustomDrawable(Bitmap bitmap){
            this.bitmap = bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isStateful() {
            // always return true
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int getOpacity() {
            // see documentation on android developers site
            return PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
        }

        @Override
        public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {
        }

        @Override
        public void setAlpha(int i) {
        }

        boolean pressed = false;

        @Override
        protected boolean onStateChange(int[] states) {
            // simplified but working
            for (int state : getState()){
                if (state == android.R.attr.state_pressed ||
                    state == android.R.attr.state_focused)
                        pressed = true;
                else pressed = false;
            }
            invalidateSelf();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            // very simplified example
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,paint);
            circlePaint.setColor(pressed ? colorActive : colorPassive);
            canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a boolean to control when the view is pressed and override onTouchEvent to set it true or false:

```
private boolean pressed;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // ...
    if (pressed){
        // code when pressed
    }
    else{
        // otherwise
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            pressed = true;
            this.invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            pressed = false;
            this.invalidate();
            break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but this will not work when parent intercepts touch events (for example when this view is placed inside ScrollView or ViewPager). In this case the view recieves DOWN but not UP when scrolling started

Comment: Try to disable interceptTouchEvent in parent when you want to handle the event: this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

Comment: I really do need parent to intercept events because of scrolling is needed. Next i have tried to implement in onTouchEvent to disallow parent on Down and allow when scroll position is higher than touch slop. But when the custom view is in other layout and that layout is placed inside scrollview more and more bugs jumping out. Thanks but this will surely not work.